# Manipulate image in div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have researched a lot but couldn't find specific solution. How to manipulate image pixels when a button is pressed? This is code I am working on:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="nhome.js"></script>
</head>
<p>Duke img</p>
<button onClick="my()"/>Click Me!</button>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function my(){
var devil = new SimpleImage("devil.png");
for(var p in devil.values()){
    p.setRed(200);
    p.setGreen(100);
}
devil.print();
}
```

Any suggestions on where I am doing wrong? I am just a beginner in js.

Comment: What is `new SimpleImage()` ?

Comment: On duke uni. programming course, there is online javascript environment where this syntax is instructed. This is exactly what I am asking for. How to implement the same in regular wamp server using html and js on my local machine?